# Put image array from $_SESSION inside a div in javascript using for loop

Tags: javascript, php, html

i have a jquery image uploader that opens in a fancybox.
When the images are uploaded, a session array with the image names will be created and the pictures will show on the next page after the form was submitted.

I need to show the images at the first page after close the fancybox.
My idea is to use the session array inside javascript and create a div for every image and put them into my parent div that has the ID "uploaded_pics".

Is there a better way or can someone help me with my code?

```
var img_arr = "<?php echo $_SESSION['UPLOADED_PICTURES'];?>";

for (var single_img of img_arr) {
var new_div = document.createElement("div");
element.appendChild(document.createTextNode("<?php echo $uploaded_path . session_id() . '/' . ;?>"single_img));
document.getElementById('uploaded_pics').appendChild(element);
}
```

Comment: A better way would be to use `json_encode($_SESSION['UPLOADED_PICTURES'])`, the problem is that you don't have access to `$_SESSION['UPLOADED_PICTURES']` on your first page containing the uploader. You need to either somehow get the picture list from your uploader or request them using ajax.

Comment: oh ok thanks! i never worked with json before. i learned everything in the last years by myself so im no professional programmer :D Can you give me some more information how to use it in my code?

Comment: `var img_arr = <?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['UPLOADED_PICTURES']) ?>;` but as I said, at the time when the first page HTML is generated, the session doesn't yet contain the images. If you add this code to the first page it's not going to work. It might be worth to look for tutorials about how to use AJAX with PHP.